# Найти в тексте все ссылки на видео YouTube

Tags: php

Есть текст, в нем могут быть ссылки на видео с ютуба, например:

```
$str = 'текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video1 текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video2 текст текст';
```

Мне нужно получить все эти ссылки на видео и заменить их на свои. Только учитываю то что в тексте могут быть и другие ссылки на ютуб (не на видео, их трогать не нужно). То есть чтобы брало только ссылки которые начинаются с `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`

Comment: ну вы уже почти составили регулярное выражение. Осталось ещё чуть-чуть

Comment: @ArchDemon с регулярками у меня вообще не идет... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант решения задачи на `JS` с помощью регулярного выражения `/watch\?v\=([A-z0-9]+)/g` и функции [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

```js
const YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/';

const str = 'текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video1 текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video2 текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6sj10I8NFo';

const matches = str.matchAll(/watch\?v\=([A-z0-9]+)/g);

for (const [match, link] of Array.from(matches)) {
    const element_a = document.createElement('a');
    element_a.innerText = link;
    element_a.href = YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL + match;
    element_a.target = '_blank';
    links.appendChild(element_a);
}
```

```css
a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="links"></div>
```

---

Вариант на `PHP` - [в песочнице](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bdaed8548402ff27eeb1987a955dcaefda6b680e)

```
<?php

$str = 'текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video1 текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video2 текст текст https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6sj10I8NFo';

preg_match_all('/watch\?v\=([A-z0-9]+)/', $str, $result);

print_r($result[1]);
```

Comment: Это всё прекрасно, но у автора стоит метка PHP

Comment: @Mcile я обновил ответ

Comment: Ничёсе, работает